# Hibernate doesn't return manually INSERTed rows

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flashback

I'm having an issue with my jpa repository doesn't return rows that I've manually inserted into the database (Oracle) via good old SQL

```
Insert into SYSTEM.USER (ID,CREDENTIALS,ISADMIN) values (USERSEQ.nextval,'foo',1);
```

**My Jpa Repository**

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

**User entity**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgen")
  @SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1, name = "idgen", sequenceName = "userseq")
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String credentials;

  private boolean isAdmin;
}
```

The super weird thing is that entries that I've inserted via the REST interface works!

So if I create:

- User A via REST API
- User B via SQL statement
- User C via REST API

The result of `GET /api/users` is `A, C`

After pulling out all my hair. I think I've narrowed it down to the Flashback feature Oracle has. As only A and C has entries in the Flashback. So Hibernate must do some magic behind the scene.

So my question is. How do I insert a row using SQL so it get a flashback entry also.

If the flashback thing isn't the problem. How do I make Hibernate return all the rows then?

Comment: Did you `commit`ed your `insert`?

Comment: Hmm didn't know there was a `commit` keyword in oracle :)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber `COMMIT WORK;` worked! Thank you!

Comment: Glead to be helpfull;) and yes, there is no `autocommit=TRUE` if you use the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

while you are executing the SQL query in **Oracle Sql Developer** that time it is working own session. and JPA is working own session. i.e. JPA is not able to access the SQL query's records.

**solution**

```
Insert into SYSTEM.USER (ID,CREDENTIALS,ISADMIN) values (USERSEQ.nextval,'foo',1);
```

after that just fire the `COMMIT` command in **Oracle Sql Developer**.

it is working for me.